# csv2json.py error

Tags: python, django, json, csv

I am trying to run the script [csv2json.py](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1680/) in the Command Prompt, but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\A\Documents\PROJECTS\Django\sw2>csv2json.py csvtest1.csv wkw1.Lawyer
Converting C:\Users\A\Documents\PROJECTS\Django\sw2csvtest1.csv from CSV to JSON as  C:\Users\A\Documents\PROJECTS\Django\sw2csvtest1.csv.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A\Documents\PROJECTS\Django\sw2\csv2json.py", line 37, in <module>
    f = open(in_file, 'r' )
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  'C:\\Users\\A\\Documents\\PROJECTS\\Django\\sw2csvtest1.csv'
```

Here are the relevant lines from the snippet:

```
31 in_file = dirname(__file__) + input_file_name 
32 out_file = dirname(__file__) + input_file_name + ".json" 
34 print "Converting %s from CSV to JSON as %s" % (in_file, out_file) 
36 f = open(in_file, 'r' ) 
37 fo = open(out_file, 'w')
```

It seems that the directory name and file name are combined. How can I make this script run?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Altering lines 31 and 32 as answered by Denis Otkidach worked fine. But I realized that the first column name needs to be pk and each row needs to start with an integer:

```
for row in reader:
    if not header_row:
        header_row = row
        continue

    pk = row[0]
    model = model_name
    fields = {}
    for i in range(len(row)-1):
        active_field = row[i+1]
```

So my csv row now looks like this (including the header row):

```
pk, firm_url, firm_name, first, last, school, year_graduated
1, http://www.graychase.com/aabbas, Gray & Chase, Amr A, Babas, The George Washington University Law School, 2005
```

Is this a requirement of the django fixture or json format? If so, I need to find a way to add the pk numbers to each row. Can I delete this pk column? Any suggestions?

**Edit 2**

I keep getting this ValidationError: "This value must be an integer". There is only one integer field and that's the pk. Is there a way to find out from the traceback what the line numbers refer to?

```
Problem installing fixture   'C:\Users\A\Documents\Projects\Django\sw2\wkw2\fixtures\csvtest1.csv.json': Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.py",  line 150, in handle
  for obj in objects:

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 41, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(simplejson.load(stream)):

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\python.py", line 95, in Deserializer
    data[field.attname] = field.rel.to._meta.get_field(field.rel.field_name).to_python(field_value)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 356, in to_python
    _("This value must be an integer."))

ValidationError: This value must be an integer.
```

Comment: I think it would be better to post separate question instead of updating this one, since your update is not clarification of original question.

Comment: Yes, I was just doing that, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894628/django-loaddata-validationerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is used incorrectly here, the proper way to combine directory name and file name is using `os.path.join()`. But there is no need to combine directory where script is located with file name, since it's common to pass relative path to current working directory. So, change lines 31-32 to the following:

```
in_file = input_file_name
out_file = in_file + '.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from os import path
in_file = path.join(dirname(__file__), input_file_name )
out_file = path.join(dirname(__file__), input_file_name + ".json" )
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `os.path.join` rather than just concatenating `dirname()` and filenames.

```
import os.path
in_file = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), input_file_name)
out_file = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), input_file_name + ".json")
```

will fix your problem, though depending on what exactly you're doing, there's probably a more elegant way to do it.